# MVC 4 where to write mapping logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a MVC 4 website where my controller calls a service and I have to map (one to one mapping) back the response to my viewmodel. There are three possible approaches I could think of :-

1. Have the mapping in the controller itself
2. Have a separate mapping layer ( a separate folder in my project) where all  my mapping logic will reside and controller will call this method
3. Have the mapping logic inside the viewmodel class.

Idea 2 and 3 looks better obviously because the mapping methods can be reused across controllers.

But I am confused on which among 2 , 3 to use.
If I use approach 2, the responsibilities will be well defined but will add another class file which might make the solution little less maintainable in long run

If I use approach 3, then the mapping logic is confined inside the viewmodel but I feel it violates SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) as the viewmodel class has the responsibility of display elements and mapping logic both.

Is there a good practice regarding  where should we put the mapping logic?
If you have got any links please share those too.

Comment: about what kind of mapping are you talking?

Comment: I am talking about manual one to one mapping of objects

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd say stop killing yourself and just use something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/), but if you want to go the manual route, I'd recommend option 2 for the largely the same reason I recommend AutoMapper: this type of thing belongs in a library. I don't see how this would be any harder to maintain. In fact, have all your mapping logic contained in one class or several classes all in one location in your project sounds *far* easier to maintain than any other solution.

Comment: Thanks Chris, even I feel the same but couldn't find a sample project or article related to this, do you have few references handy with you?

Comment: For setting up a mapping library? No, unfortunately, but I think the lack of resources is due to the nature of this type of thing. There's already a number of libraries out there to solve this problem (AutoMapper is just one, but there's others). Usually, if you're doing mapping enough to need to create a library for it, you just use something existing rather than recreating the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I would advocate Option #2, because of the clearly defined responsibility of the mapping layer class(es).

The obvious location of the mapping logic completely justifies the increase in the number of classes in my opinion. I liken it to have multiple JavaScript files as modules, while it increases the number of files to maintain, it gives a clearer understanding of what is responsible for what in your system.

Comment: Thanks Karl, even I feel the same but couldnt find a sample project or article related to this, do you have few references handy with you?